# Sweetalert2 is breaking my Angular2 build

Tags: angular, uglifyjs, sweetalert, rollup, aot

I am using a pretty standard AOT and Rollup build per the [Angular Cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html):

rollup.config.js:

```
import rollup      from 'rollup'
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs    from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify      from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

export default {
    entry: 'app/main-aot.js',
    dest: 'dist/process-tracker.js', // output a single application bundle
    sourceMap: true,
    sourceMapFile: 'dist/process-tracker.js.map',
    format: 'iife',
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
        commonjs({
            include: ['node_modules/**'],
            namedExports: {
                'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js': ['merge', 'clone', 'cloneDeep']
            }
        }),
        uglify()
    ]
}
```

tsconfig-aot.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },

  "files": [
    "app/app.module.ts",
    "app/main-aot.ts"
  ],

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true
  }
}
```

Everything compiled and uglified as expected initially, but I recently created a dialog service that takes a dependency on [sweetalert2](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2). Now when I run my aot and rollup tasks, the uglify step fails with `Error transforming bundle with 'uglify' plugin: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)`

I traced this down to the sweetalert code in my bundle:

```
const swalPrefix = 'swal2-';

const prefix = (items) => {
  const result = {};
  for (const i in items) {
    result[items[i]] = swalPrefix + items[i];
  }
  return result
};
```

So the fat arrow functions from this lib are passing through the compiler untouched. UglifyJS blows up because it does not support this syntax yet. I've monkeyed around with how I configure SystemJS, but that hasn't changed the behavior. This is what I have currently:

```
map: {
    'sweetalert2': 'npm:sweetalert2'
}

packages: {
    sweetalert2: {
        main: './dist/sweetalert2.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can get the ngc compiler or rollup to pay attention to this third-party code and translate it to ES5?

UPDATE:

The answer must be in the way SystemJS works? The dist files, which I'm pointing to, do not have the ES6 syntax -- they have clearly been transpiled. So why are the actual source files getting pulled in?

UPDATED UPDATE:

No, this can' be a SystemJS thing. It has to be in Rollup or one of the plugins. I've poured through the documentation and issues for the commonjs and node-resolve plugins, but haven't found anything that helps me understand what's going on. I've changed the commonjs include array to be less general, but no change:

```
include: [
    'node_modules/rxjs/**',
    'node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/**',
    'node_modules/lodash/**'
],
```

Comment: might want to look into using [babel](https://babeljs.io) to transpile ur sweet alert.

it also looks like theres a [rollup-plugin](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel) to help you with rollup-babel integrations

Comment: I thought about that, but the library has already been transpiled (the dist folder), but the bundle is including the raw ES6 source from the src folder.

Comment: Any updates on this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I gave up and pull the SweetAlert2 dependency from a CDN (both js and css). In newer projects I've gone to using Angular-CLI and angular material.